# Program stops working when adding new code

Tags: c, audio, capture, alsa

I am trying to capture data via ALSA API using this c code:

```
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main() {
long loops;
int rc;
int size;
snd_pcm_t *handle;
snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
unsigned int val;
int dir;
snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
char *buffer;

/* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
if (rc < 0) {
fprintf(stderr,
        "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
        snd_strerror(rc));
exit(1);
}

/* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

/* Fill it in with default values. */
snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

/* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

/* Interleaved mode */
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                  SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

/* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,
                          SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

/* Two channels (stereo) */
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

/* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
val = 44100;
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params,
                              &val, &dir);

/* Set period size to 32 frames. */
frames = 32;
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle,
                          params, &frames, &dir);

/* Write the parameters to the driver */
rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
if (rc < 0) {
fprintf(stderr,
        "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
        snd_strerror(rc));
  exit(1);
}

/* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params,
                                  &frames, &dir);
size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
buffer = (char *) malloc(size);

/* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params,
                                     &val, &dir);
loops = 5000000 / val;

while (loops > 0) {
loops--;
rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
if (rc == -EPIPE) {
  /* EPIPE means overrun */
  fprintf(stderr, "overrun occurred\n");
  snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
} else if (rc < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr,
          "error from read: %s\n",
          snd_strerror(rc));
} else if (rc != (int)frames) {
  fprintf(stderr, "short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
}
rc = write(1, buffer, size);
if (rc != size)
  fprintf(stderr,
          "short write: wrote %d bytes\n", rc);
}

snd_pcm_drain(handle);
snd_pcm_close(handle);
free(buffer);

return 0;
}
```

So the code actually works, but if I add another loop into the "while (loops > 0)" for example:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<128;i++){
printf("I: %i \n", i);
}
```

the output of the program will be:

```
unable to set hw parameters: Invalid argument
```

I really don't understand how a simple loop at the end can affect a program at the beginning? Does anyone know how to fix/prevent that error?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you show us the code that works, not the code that doesn't work?

Comment: This looks like C. Any reason you added the C++ tag? C++ is a different language, in general compiling C code as C++ is a bad idea. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!

Comment: *"The same error appears if the code is compiled with g++, with gcc no problem."* A C++ compiler rejecting (possibly) valid C code is not a surprise.

Comment: Thanks StoryTeller for your input, but the compiler does not reject the code at all, it is the program that does not work after compiling.

Comment: Your problem is, that `dir` is uninitialized and contains a somewhat random value. Initialize it correctly and your problem will vanish.

Comment: A "thank you" would have been nice...

Comment: I am sooo sorry, THANKS A LOT Ctx!

Answer (score 0):

The error  ***unable to set hw parameters: Invalid argument*** is not due to your additional code snippet.
The actual reason of error is uninitialized `dir` variable. 
To fix that issue, you have to initialize `dir` properly or pass `0`or `NULL` instead of `&dir` .